# Alerting for jenkin jobs stuck with no executors

Tags: jenkins, prometheus

We have multiple Jenkin masters and have enabled Jenkins Prometheus plugin and connected these masters as data sources to Grafana. I am currently interested in finding jobs which are waiting for executors for more than a certain time and create an alert based on this. I looked at [Jenkins metrics](https://plugins.jenkins.io/metrics/) but did not find any suitable metric to have monitoring for this use case. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **access the Jenkins build queue via Groovy** and check for entries waiting for too long.

It is possible to **run Groovy scripts via the Jenkins REST API**, which then will be your interface for polling for such "blocked" jobs.

Comment: I am actually looking for a plugin as we have hundreds of jobs to monitor, if nothing is available I guess we can run a custom job which monitors all our Jenkins jobs and publish these metrics

Comment: The number of jobs to be monitored has no impact here. You'd scan the build queue and report items pending for too long. Personally, I'd favour submitting a few lines of Groovy via REST over a custom plugin+extra job, but it's certainly I matter of taste : )